# apache config dynamic documentroot

Tags: apache, configuration, virtualhost

we are programming a website in a test environment.
This website will have 2 languages
with urls like domain-language.com
eventually we need to switch over to a situation like domain/language.com

can we set up apache so that it can listen to domain/language.com
and depending on the approach the documentroot changes towards the subfolder of the aproached language? because we have a lot of hardcoded links on our website which might all have to be changed if the documentroot is a level higher .

the folder structure how i think it will look like is

/-
  language1
  language2
if i browse towards domain/language1.com i should get the subfolder language 1 as documentroot , making it the /

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't use "/" within a domain name I guess. "/" is always using in Apache and browser as a delimiter between domain name and file/sub-folder. Hence try to use other symbols  like "-", "_" etc to replace the "/". In fact, it's definitely possible to set different Docroot for different domains.. any change in domain name (in your case it's language1 and language2) is considered as a different domain which can be mapped to separate DocRoot folder.